# Unique form with many tables

Tags: forms, ms-access, primary-key

I'm trying to create a form to fill three tables to describe some projects with  the 'Title of the project' as common field. When I create the form I have to write the title three times, otherwise it's not posible to fill the tables. Is there any way to put just one of the three fields on the form but the three of them are filled?

The database is empty, I want to make a form to start introducing all the projects that are going to be done in my group of work. In one table there are data related to the project, like start dat , full budget etc. In another one the information about my company, like the group its doing it, its role etc. In the last one just some general information like related tags. The name of the project appears in all of them, but when I do the form from a query they seem not to be related even if I do it on the query.

I've already tried to do it with the Wizard tool, selecting the different tables and its fields. I also tried to check the form properties...but I can't come up with what I'm doing wrong...

I'm new using access...

Comment: Some examples will help us to understand well. Please add into the question

Comment: Using this text field as PK/FK is not good design. This is a design issue, not programming. Question is not appropriate for SO.